# Group by two columns in a dataframe then display averages of two other column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

A sample of my datframe, df_Done_Avg_Salesperson_Volume

```
    state   currency_str    sales_person_name2  rfq_qty    rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv
    Done      USD           AY                  200000.0    155720.0
    Done      USD           AY                  1000000.0   778600.0
    Done      USD           AY                  200000.0    155720.0
    Done      GBP           YJJ                 25000000.0  14140000.0
    Done      GBP           YJJ                 2500000.0   1946500.0
```

I would like to group by sales_person_name2 and currency_str but display the average of rfq_qty and  rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv.

```
sales_person_name2  currency_str`   Avg rfq_qty  Avg rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv
AY                  USD             466666.6667  363346.6667
YJJ                 GBP             13750000    8043250
```

When I try to combine the two I get a tuple error

```
d = {
        ('rfq_qty',np.mean)
        ('rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv',np.mean)
    }
display(df_Done_Avg_Salesperson_Volume.groupby(['sales_person_name2','currency_str'])['rfq_qty','rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv'].agg(d).reset_index())

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Is there a way to group on a series of columns but display statitical summations on two other columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
df.groupby(['sales_person_name2','currency_str'], as_index=False)['rfq_qty','rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv'].mean()
```

Output:

```
  sales_person_name2    currency_str    rfq_qty        rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv
0   AY                   USD       466666.6666666667    363346.6666666667
1   YJJ                  GBP          13750000.0           8043250.0
```

If you must use `.agg()`, you need a dictionary.

```
d = {
        'rfq_qty':np.mean,
        'rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv':np.mean
    }
df.groupby(['sales_person_name2','currency_str'], as_index=False)['rfq_qty','rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv'].agg(d))
```

Comment: Thanks @Harv Ipan. Appreciate it!